# Unable to verify/create output bucket bucket-name Shows a different bucket name than the specified as output location

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

While trying to query AWS athena, I am getting the error

> Unable to verify/create output bucket root-bucket-name

In the output location I have specified the location as `s3://root-bucket-name/athena/data`

But the error is shown for `root-bucket-name`

I have full access to this bucket `s3://root-bucket-name/athena/data` but not to the root bucket.

Have s3:* access to resources

```
"arn:aws:s3:::root-bucket-name/athena/data/",
"arn:aws:s3:::root-bucket-name/athena/data/*",
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: The bucket is `root-bucket-name`, not `root-bucket-name/athena/data`. So what permissions exactly do you have?

Comment: @Marcin

I have S3:* access to "arn:aws:s3:::root-bucket-name/athena/data/",

Answer (score 0):

The error "Unable to verify/create output bucket root-bucket-name" is likely caused by a missing IAM permission for AWS Athena. Specifically, Athena requires the S3 permission for GetBucketLocation to use the bucket as an output location.
To troubleshoot this error use this link for the AWS Knowledge centre to help as a reference. ["Unable to verify/create output bucket" error in Amazon Athena](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/athena-output-bucket-error)